# Rails app stopped running locally after pushing it to Heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I pushed a (very simple) Rails app up to Heroku, the build was successful and it works online (minus some route issues), but now I can't get it to run locally. It's actually a clone of the "getting started" app I thought I'd modify to avoid deployment issues. When I try to start a Rails server I get the following message:

```
        $ rails s
    Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

    In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
    like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

    Here's how to upgrade:

      bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
      rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
      git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

    You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

    When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
    generate it and add it to source control:

      bundle binstubs some-gem-name
      git add bin/new-executable

    Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
    Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
    Backtrace for gem load error is:
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:1:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `block in (root)'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `block in require'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747:in `tap'
    C:/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `(root)'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1:in `(root)'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `block in server'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1298:in `loop'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:1:in `<main>'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:979:in `load'
    C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    Bundler Error Backtrace:

      block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85
                  each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734
      block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77
                  each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734
               require at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
               require at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108
                <main> at C:/blog/config/application.rb:7
               require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
       block in (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1
                   tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747
                server at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78
                server at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75
                <main> at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
               require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
       block in (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
                  loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1298
                (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:1
                <main> at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45
               require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
               require at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
                <main> at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34
                  load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:979
                <main> at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/bin/rails:22
```

Removing uglifier and coffee-rails gets the app up and running locally so, I tried that and followed the upgrade instructions, then used bundle install to add them again, with the same result. I also can't push a version of this app up to Heroku without those gems so I'm left scratching my head where to go from here.

Here is a copy of the app I pushed to Git (excuse the language on one of the commits I was quite frustrated) to help with trouble shooting

https://github.com/taswelldavis/blog

Thanks for the help,
Anna

Comment: This seems unrelated to your deploy. Did you remove Node or one of the runtimes mentioned on the page referenced in that error? https://github.com/rails/execjs

Comment: No but I SSHed into my Pi shortly after deploying so maybe that messed with my environment variables? Installing node.js fixed the issue.

Comment: It's possible that the JavaScript runtime it was looking for disappeared from your path and it couldn't find it when it needed to. If you've got a synopsis of how you fixed this, adding a self-answer could help others in the same jam.